# Pass phone number to PayPal Form, parallel payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using Adaptive Payments API, All information from my form to PayPal's form is transferring (Name, address, city, state, zip etc...) except the phone number.

I am using the fields below for phone number. Is there another way?

```
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="708">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="555">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1234">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after not being to find it anywhere in the documentation. I took a wild guess and copied the field name from PayPal's form into my form.

To populate the phone number using adaptive payments you must using the following field in the form posting to PayPal.

```
<input type="hidden" name="H_PhoneNumber" value="555-555-5555">
```